# Getting the datatype of a json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, types

Hi I have a below json value

```
    {
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "0001",
      "data": {
        "data1": [
          {
            "data2": [
              {
                "id": "5001",
                "type": "None",
                "dummyData": [
                  {
                    "data3": "5001",
                    "data4": [
                      {
                        "data5": "5001"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find the jsonpath aand the datatype of the keys in the json object.(ie) jsonpath of item will be item=item and the datatype will be item = array of JSON objects.I'm able to find the jsonpath.Below is my code

```
var data={"item":[{"id":"0001","data":{"data1":[{"data2":[{"id":"5001","type":"None","dummyData":[{"data3":"5001","data4":[{"data5":"5001"}]}]}]}]}}]}

var keys = new Array();

keys = getKeys(keys, data, '');





console.log("key"+keys)
function getKeys(keys, obj, path) {
for (key in obj) {
    var currpath = path + '.' + key;
    keys.push([key, currpath]);
    if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
        if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {                   //added check for array
            getKeys(keys, obj[key][0], currpath + '[]');
        }
        else
            getKeys(keys, obj[key], currpath);
    }
}
var jsonPath=[];
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var json = new Array();
    json = keys[i][1].replace(/^\.|\.$/g, '')
    jsonPath[jsonPath.length]= keys[i][0] + '=' + json

}

return jsonPath;
```

}

here the console key prints the jsonpath of all the keys.I need to find the datatype.I'm stuck here any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: XPath is for XML, not JSON or JavaScript structures.

Comment: sorry i meant the path of the object keys in a JSON